# What is Equivalent of Oracle Exception type in SQL SERVER

Tags: sql, sql-server

What is the Equivalent of Oracle Exception type in SQL SERVER?

For example, I Oracle I have:

ER_Wrong_Option EXCEPTION;

Is there is a similar type for TSQL? at least I could not find any.

Comment: For a start: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/try-catch-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: There is no equivalent.

Comment: If you are using TRY..CATCH.. then within the CATCH block you can use the ERROR_MESSAGE() and ERROR_NUMBER() functions (and others).  If you want to use the old-style unstructured error-checking (may be deprecated), you have to use the @@ERROR global variable.

Comment: Note that in Sql Server the error names are treated as text rather than as compiler symbolic names, but their functionality is largely equivalent.

Comment: @RbarryYoung  true, I was guessing that it may be the only option. I got Oracle code from someone very old who only knew unstructured coding. I will take a look at @@ERROR functionality. Thanks!

Comment: If you need to get the error text (name) from @@ERROR, I believe that you have to look it up in the sys.messages table, though in practice most of us just used the error number as a literal and added a comment noting which error that was.  The newer/structured methods provide it automatically through the ERROR_MESSAGE() function.

Comment: @ RBarryYoung thanks for the further explanation.

Comment: Suggest you read Erland's discussion of [error handling](https://www.sommarskog.se/error_handling/Part1.html) and bookmark his site as it contains much useful information.

Comment: @Smor Appreciate it!

Comment: @SMor Wow, great link!  I was just thinking that I wished there was some comprehensive treatment of error handling in SQL Server.  I wasn’t aware that Erland had already done it, and you can’t do better than him on something like this.  Just the whole matter with XACT_ABORT is a hard to explain mess and I wasn’t sure whether to get into or not since the OP was thinking about using @@ERROR.